# Page numbers vertically centered in the outer page margin

Tags: positioning, margins, page-numbering, koma-script, scrbook

Even though it seems to be a non-standard position, I'd like to place my document's page numbers vertically centered in the outer page margin – i.e. where you usually have your thumb when you skim through a book.

How can I achieve that with scrbook? As far as I can see the only predefined positions for page numbers are in the header and footer.

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo and egreg, both of your solutions work. I prefer egreg's one because it goes without an additional package and because it's way beyond my LaTeX skills :) p.s. I'm sorry to post this as an answer to my own question, but SX doesn't recognize me. I guess it's because I posted the question as unregistered user and now I'm registered (even though I used the same email address - anyways). Also I'm sorry for not being able to mark the question answered and give credits :(

Comment: I merged your two accounts together now (the questions was asked with an unregistered account). I also converted your post to a comment. Don't worry about it.  You can now place comments here and also accept your favored answer to conclude the question. [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: @Martin: Wow, that was quicker than quick! I was in the means of writing a mail about this, but it seems I don't need to send it anymore :) Great site, great people!

Comment: Note that you can flag posts for moderator attention which will be noticed very quickly. Use the 'flag' link below each post to do so. There is also the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) and our [meta] site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another solution with only KOMA-Script tools (and some low level trickery):

```
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\setlength{\footskip}{0pt}
\rofoot[\centerpageno{o}]{\centerpageno{o}}
\lefoot[\centerpageno{e}]{\centerpageno{e}}
\def\centerpageno#1{\leavevmode
  \vbox to 0pt{
    \vss
    \hbox to 0pt{\Huge\normalfont
      \if#1o\kern 2em\else\hss\fi\thepage
      \if#1o\hss\else\kern2em\fi}
    \vskip.5\textheight
    \vskip\baselineskip}}
```

I use the normal footer, putting into it a zero height box that contains a zero width box that is raised to the center of the text block; in it the page number is typeset shifted on the right or on the left depending if we are in an odd or even page.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `background` package; a little exampe:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetBgContents{}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgColor{black}
\SetBgScale{3}

\makeatletter
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}%
  {\SetBgPosition{1.05\textwidth,-.5\textheight}}
  {\SetBgPosition{0.3,-.5\textheight}}
  \SetBgContents{-\thepage-}
  \bg@material%
}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use KOMA-Script package `scrlayer-scrpage`. It is the successor of the deprecated package `scrpage2`.

`scrlayer-scrpage` uses layer to declare pagestyles. So you can declare a new layer for the pagenumber in the outer margin and add this layer to pagestyle `scrheadings` and `plain.scrheadings`. Note that after loading `scrlayer-scrpage` pagestyle `scrheadings` is set and pagestyle `plain` is redefined as an aliaspagestyle for `plain.scrheadings`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\headmark}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  outermargin,
  height=\textheight,
  voffset=1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep,
  contents={%
    \vfill
    \ifodd\value{page}\hspace*{.4\layerwidth}\else\hfill\fi
    \pagemark
    \ifodd\value{page}\else\hspace*{.4\layerwidth}\fi
    \vfill
  }
]{outermargin.pagenumber}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{outermargin.pagenumber}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{outermargin.pagenumber}

\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\Huge}

\usepackage{blindtext}% <- only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\chapter{Fruits}
\section{Bananas}
\Blindtext[20]
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]