# How to add page numbers and rotated chapter title to the outer margin?

Tags: xetex, header-footer, margins, koma-script, scrbook

I'd like to have page numbers on the outer page border slightly bellow the center, and the current chapter title at the bottom but rotated 90 degrees counter-clockwise (i.e. to the left) such that it also sticks to the page outer border, i.e.

```
+--------------+--------------+
|              |              |
|              |              |
|              |              |
|              |              |
|              |              |
|p             |             p|   p = page number
|              |              |
|C             |             C|   CT = chapter title, rotated
|T             |             T|        90 degrees counter-clockwise
+--------------+--------------+
```

Sure enough I could use [tikz-pgf](/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf) in a similar way as mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280160/430) (and I'm already using tikz due to that very scenario), via

```
\node [anchor=west] at ([yshift=-0.5cm] current page.west){\pagemark}
```

and similarly use it to rotate the chapter title, but isn't there a better way that maybe also respects `pagestyle`, e.g. by defining a `pagemargin` similar to `pageheader`?

Comment: If it's relevant, I am currently also using `\usepackage[top=30mm,bottom=30mm,inner=25mm,outer=35mm]{geometry}` and wouldn't mind putting that into a `pagestyle` as well...

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=chapterthumb+[koma-script]

Comment: If I understand well, you'd like to have the header (or the footer) in the outer margin? Do you already use a package like `fancyhdr` or `titleps` (the latter from `titlesec`)?

Comment: @Bernard Correct, and no, none of these so far

Comment: @Johannes_B Ok, it's nice to know that's basically solved via `chapterthumbs.sty`... Then I guess I should read through [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184011/how-to-get-chapterthumbs-match-their-chapter-titles-in-koma-script)...

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24362/430, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40319/430

Comment: Wait, the position of the chapter title is fixed and doesn't move?

Comment: @Johannes_B _Oh_, now I get what you meant... yes, it's always at the same position for all chapters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using package `scrlayer-scrpage` to define a new page style:

```
\documentclass[
  %oneside
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[top=30mm,bottom=30mm,inner=25mm,outer=35mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}

% new font element for the text in outermargin
\newkomafont{outermargin}{\scshape\Large}

% declare new layers for the outermargin
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  outermargin,
  oddpage,
  contents={\rotatebox{90}{\parbox[b][\layerwidth][b]{\layerheight}{%
    \hspace*{.5cm}\parbox[b]{.35\layerheight}{\usekomafont{outermargin}\headmark}%
    \vspace*{.5cm}}}}
]{ChapterInOutermargin.odd}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=ChapterInOutermargin.odd,
  evenpage,
  contents={\rotatebox{90}{\parbox[t][\layerwidth][t]{\layerheight}{%
    \vspace*{.5cm}%
    \hspace*{.5cm}\parbox[t]{.35\layerheight}{\usekomafont{outermargin}\headmark}}}}
]{ChapterInOutermargin.even}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=ChapterInOutermargin.odd,
  contents={\parbox{\layerwidth}{\vspace*{.55\layerheight}%
      \hfill\usekomafont{outermargin}\pagemark\hspace*{.5cm}}}
  ]{PagenumberInOutermargin.odd}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=ChapterInOutermargin.even,
  contents={\parbox{\layerwidth}{\vspace*{.55\layerheight}%
      \hspace*{.5cm}\usekomafont{outermargin}\pagemark\hfill}}
  ]{PagenumberInOutermargin.even}

% declare new page styles using the new layers
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{outermargin}{%
  ChapterInOutermargin.odd,ChapterInOutermargin.even,%
  PagenumberInOutermargin.odd,PagenumberInOutermargin.even}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{plain.outermargin}{%
  PagenumberInOutermargin.odd,PagenumberInOutermargin.even}

% if page style plain should be an alias for plain.outermargin
\RedeclarePageStyleAlias{plain}{plain.outermargin}

% use the new page style
\pagestyle{outermargin}
% if chapter pages should use page style outermargin instead plain
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{outermargin}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks. In case anyone's interested, one can of course use `\usekomafont{pagenumber}` in the respective layers to have a different font for pagenumbers, and `\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}` to hide chapter numbers. **edit** Never mind `\usekomafont{pagenumber}`, that should be implicitly included in `\pagemark` - @esdd, shouldn't that be a `\thepage` instead to avoid using the `pagenumber` font?

Comment: I suggest to use `\pagemark`. Then you have to use `\setkomafont` or `\addtokomafont` only once to change the font of all page numbers. If you do not want to use a special `pagenumber` font insert `\setkomafont{pagenumber}{}` in your preamble.