# Page number at the bottom outer page margin

Tags: koma-script, page-numbering

I'm trying to put the page number aligned with the last baseline on a page. With no luck. Is it possible? Or how can I put page number on the bottom of the outer margin?

[image]

This is very similar case, but it's vertically centered.

```
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  outermargin,
  height=\textheight,
  voffset=1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep,
  contents={%
    \vfill
    \ifodd\value{page}\hspace*{.4\layerwidth}\else\hfill\fi
    \pagemark
    \ifodd\value{page}\else\hspace*{.4\layerwidth}\fi
    \vfill
  }
```

[Page numbers vertically centered in the outer page margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24362/page-numbers-vertically-centered-in-the-outer-page-margin/373254)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the last `\vfill` from the `\DeclareNewLayer` code in [esdd's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373254/150114):

```
\DeclareNewLayer[
background,
outermargin,
height=\textheight,
voffset=1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep,
contents={%
    \vfill
    \ifodd\value{page}\hspace*{.4\layerwidth}\else\hfill\fi
    \pagemark
    \ifodd\value{page}\else\hspace*{.4\layerwidth}\fi
    % \vfill
}
]{outermargin.pagenumber}
```

You can use the MWE in the linked answer to test it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion that works for onesided and twosided documents:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\headmark}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  oneside,
  outermargin,
  height=\textheight,
  voffset=1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep,
  contents={%
    \parbox[b][\layerheight][b]{\layerwidth}
      {\hspace*{.4\layerwidth}\pagemark}%
  }
]{outermargin.pagenumber.oneside}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=outermargin.pagenumber.oneside,
  twoside,
  oddpage
]{outermargin.pagenumber.odd}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=outermargin.pagenumber.odd,
  evenpage,
  contents={%
    \parbox[b][\layerheight][b]{\layerwidth}
      {\hfill\pagemark\hspace*{.4\layerwidth}}%
  }
]{outermargin.pagenumber.even}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{%
  outermargin.pagenumber.oneside,%
  outermargin.pagenumber.odd,%
  outermargin.pagenumber.even%
}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{%
  outermargin.pagenumber.oneside,%
  outermargin.pagenumber.odd,%
  outermargin.pagenumber.even%
}


\usepackage{showframe}% <- only for showing the page layout
\usepackage{blindtext}% <- only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\chapter{Fruits}
\section{Bananas}
\Blindtext[20]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Or with option `oneside` for `scrbook`:

[image]

Comment: since this solution works fine in latex, how can i get simmilar effect that works with context?

Comment: Maybe you have to ask a new question with tag `context`?