# Page number at the bottom outer page margin ConTeX solution

Tags: page-numbering, context

Can I put page number on the bottom of the outer margin?

[image]

Please, take a look at awesome answers in this question. It works fine with Latex. Can I get ConTeX solution?

[Page number at the bottom outer page margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406425/page-number-at-the-bottom-outer-page-margin)

Comment: `\setuppagenumbering[location=inmargin]` but that will still be in the footer.

Answer (score 5):

The place the page number in the margins of the text area you can use the `\setuptexttexts` commands which takes the same arguments as the commands to place header and footer texts. The exact position of the number can be controlled with a frame where you set the vertical and horizontal position with the `align` key.

```
\setuppagenumbering[location=none]

\setuptexttexts[margin][][{\framed[frame=off,width=max,height=max,align={middle,low}]{\prefixedpagenumber}}]

\showframe

\starttext
\dorecurse{10}{\input lorem\par}
\stoptext
```

[image: Page number in the margins of the text area]

Comment: `\setuptexttexts`.  I didn't know that one.  (+1)

Comment: It' almost perfect..but...How to change vertical position of page number to match baseline? I can change it even manually, but how?

Comment: @ReRunner When you enable blank lines between paragraphs (`\setupwhitespace[big]`) the last line of the page will be at the same height as the page number.

Comment: @ReRunner `\framed[frame=off,width=max,height=max,align={middle,low},offset=\dimexpr\topskip-\strutht+.5\linewidth\relax]{\prefixedpagenumber}`

Answer (score 2):

There is no predefined `location` in the outer margin of the text block.  You have to use layers for that.  I adapted a really old solution of Wolfgang [on the mailing list](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2013/070939.html).  You can consult his post if you need doublesided page numbers.

```
\setuppagenumbering[location=]

\definelayer
  [pagenumber]
  [width=\rightmarginwidth,
   height=\textheight]

\startsetups[pagenumber]
  \setlayer
    [pagenumber]
    [preset=middlebottom]
    {\strut\pagenumber}
\stopsetups

\setupbackgrounds[state=repeat]

\setupbackgrounds
  [text][rightmargin]
  [background=pagenumber,
   setups=pagenumber]

\starttext

\dorecurse{10}{\input lorem}

\stoptext
```

[image]